# Swift - move rain emitter to front

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, skemitternode

How do I arrange the rain emitter to the front. When I run the project the rain shows up behind the different views I have in my storyboard. I want it to show up in the front.

Comment: Maybe try setting the `zPosition` of the node to a higher value so it gets rendered later?  [An example with an SKSpriteNode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155226/how-to-bring-a-skspritenode-to-front)

Comment: I set the zPosition of the emitter to 1 and nothing changes

Comment: Try something higher. Your other Nodes may have higher zPositions

Comment: I also tried much higher numbers. I need it to be in front of image views not other nodes